# Replacing multiple string in one column that follow specific pattern

Tags: regex

I have multiple strings in one column that follow this pattern:

```
ws.spik..group_1._log
ws2..group_8._log
wsn..group_11._log
```

I'm using regex to extract everything that is after the two points `..` (including the two points.
For this, I'm using the following line:

```
l_data_melted_log_v2$variable <- gsub("\\..*?_group_.*?_log", "", l_data_melted_log_v2$variable)

or

l_data_melted_log_v2$variable <- sub("\\..*?_group_.*?_log", "", l_data_melted_log_v2$variable)
```

Where, l_data_melted_log_v2 is my df and variable one of the column that contain the strings.
However, I got the same string without any change.
My expected result is:

```
ws.spik
ws2
wsn
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your regex, `_group` does not match since none of your test strings has `group` preceded by an underscore. Try removing it: `\\..*?group_.*?_log`

Comment: `\.\.group_.*?_log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex has several issues, one of which is that you don't escape the second dot in `..`.  I suggest the following simple option:

```r
l_data_melted_log_v2$variable <- gsub("\\.\\..*", "", l_data_melted_log_v2$variable)
```